# MySQL Using only percentage of result

Tags: mysql, percentage

I'm looking to take only a percent of the sum result and wondered the easiest way of doing it

```
Sum(if(activities.code >= 2998 AND activities.code <= 3590 AND sessions.type = 'Agent', 1,if(activities.code IN (5005, 5010), 1,0))) / (Sum(TIME_TO_SEC(calls.end_time) - TIME_TO_SEC(calls.start_time)) / 3600) AS SPH
```

This will come back with 1.5 for example, but I only want to take 48% of this which is 0.72

Any help would be good

Thanks

Comment: `... / 3600) * 0.48 AS SPH` ?!?

Comment: Thanks. 
Why I was trying to over complicate it I have no idea! :)